# Code first or Model first (Entity Framework/RIA Services)

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

We are developing LOB apps for many potential customers that are small or mid size, not large.

We will have to install the database for each new customer.

What do you think is the best approach for us, Model first (using edmx and using the wizzard to develop the model and metadata) or Code First.

We like the simplicity of Entity Framework/RIA Services, and we think that the Optimistic Concurrency is enough for our apps, but as the database must be installed from scratch in SQL Server (we won't use other database), we are not sure what approach is best for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as EF and the choice about edmx/code first I believe it's more a matter of personal preferences. Edmx model seems easier than code first however the designer is still a bit clunky even in VS2012 especially if you have 50+ entities. I've abandoned edmx since EF code first has become usable.
About WCF Ria Services I use it extensively in my LOB applications, even in a large one and most of the time it saves you a lot of glue code comparing to plain WCF.
 I'm sure you know about the well published features such as

- server side filtering, paging and even grouping
- Client code generation that ease the sharing of code between sl and the full clr

and many others, but maybe you're more interested in his limitations

- you can't query from the client with a nested expression (i.e. Any) though you can always add a parameter to your query and apply the filter server side, but it's not quite the same
- you can't directly expose many to many relations with silverlight (have however a look at [M2M4RIA](http://m2m4ria.codeplex.com/))
- you must add the foreign key field to your model (to me it seems like DB leaking into the the model)
- WCF Ria services do most of his work in the main thread (i.e. loading the DomainContext after a load/submitchanges)
- If your application get big and you're thinking to split your domainservices/domaincontext, be aware that you'll encounter serious pain trying to submit the changes of the two domaincontext in an atomic transaction
- Proxy generation will happen everytime you build your client and take (I think) longer than it should

Despite that I believe it's a good technologies for RAD and things may eventually turn better: [Colin Blair has posted on his blog that him is pushing Microsoft in order to release WCF Ria as opensource](http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/Musings-on-WCF-RIA-Services-4-A-Plan-for-the-Future.aspx), and this can really improve things given that Microsoft has killed Sl/Wcf ria development

Comment: Thank you!, your answer is what we needed